# Synchronization between draw and compute commands with BufferMemory barriers

Tags: synchronization, vulkan, compute-shader

I've got yet another synchronization problem.

Let's say I've got a buffer with geometry, let's call it `geometry_buffer`. I first have to fill it within compute pass, then use this buffer for rasterization and then use it in another compute pass. And I use one command buffer for all of it.

So, my questions:

0. I've seen the diagrams with pipeline stages and how compute stage is practically the last, but I've got some doubts. If I push `draw`/`draw_indexed` and then `compute` in the same command buffer exactly in this order, will compute dispatch run only after the rasterization stages are done?
1. How do I properly set BufferMemory barriers for this `geometry_buffer`?

The pipeline should be `compute_1 -> draw -> compute_2`. Is it enough to set

`COMPUTE_SHADER/SHADER_WRITE -> VERTEX_INPUT/VERTEX_READ`

barrier after the `compute_1` and then set back

`VERTEX_INPUT/VERTEX_READ -> COMPUTE_SHADER/SHADER_WRITE`

barrier after the `compute_2`? Or should I also set barrier inbetween the draw command and the `compute_2` even though the stages are consecutive and the difference is only in access bits

`VK_ACCESS_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE_READ_BIT ->  VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT`?

Or should I just change the access bits in the first barrier to

`VK_ACCESS_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT`?

Would there be a difference?

Comment: "*compute_1 -> draw -> compute_2*" You mean "compute_1 -> render pass -> compute_2". You cannot issue a compute shader dispatch *within* a render pass. So you're not just doing a single draw; you're doing *all* of the draws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write-after-read operations do not require a memory barrier; they only need an execution barrier. You need to ensure that all of the vertex input stage reading is done before the subsequent compute stage executes. That could be done with a pure post-render pass execution barrier.

Also, the barrier should come before the consuming dispatch operation, not *after* it.

> I've seen the diagrams with pipeline stages and how compute stage is practically the last, but I've got some doubts.

Implicit ordering of stage execution only applies to specific sets of stages executed by different commands. The pipelines invoked by a graphics rendering operation for example are ordered relative to one another. But they are *not* ordered relative to action commands that use different pipelines.

So the compute stage is unordered relative to any graphics stage.